# How do I copy and paste between my local system and the remote system when using rdesktop on Linux?

Tags: linux, copy-paste, rdesktop

On Linux I do:

```
rdesktop remotepc
```

How do I copy and paste between my local system and the remote system?

Comment: rdesktop -r clipboard:[off|PRIMARYCLIPBOARD|CLIPBOARD]

Comment: For clarification, the difference between CLIPBOARD and PRIMARYCLIPBOARD is that the former copies the normal clipboard, while the later chooses between the PRIMARY, which is the clipboard you copy to if you just select something, and the normal clipboard. I just figured out that -r clipboard:PRIMARYCLIPBOARD has problems with some java applications. If the clipboard owner does not provide a timestamp, rdesktop cannot copy/paste it.

Comment: Note that you have two clipboards in Linux.  I can copy to remote desktop if I right-click and then click "Copy", but not if I simply select text (which is what I normally do for copy-paste within Linux).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using RDPv5 to connect, it should automatically set the protocol to RDPv5, but in some situations it will not.

Alternatively, try launching with these arguments:

```
-5 -K -r clipboard:CLIPBOARD
```

-5 forces RDPv5 (which it should use anyway, but sometimes it doesn't), -K forces it to not override the WM's key bindings, and -r clipboard:CLIPBOARD enables clipboard redirection (which is what you want).

Comment: I know this is fairly old but when you say `WM's key bindings`, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey It means the Window Manager's key bindings. You can read the software's documentation for more info.