# Copy and paste not working under rdesktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, windows-server-2008, rdesktop

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04, connecting to a Windows 2008 box. I've got [rdesktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rdesktop) configured to use RDPv5 (using RDPv4 is known to cause clipboard issues).

The clipboard has worked just fine for most of the time that I've been using rdesktop (I've had the machine installed for a year and a half or so).  The other day, I was running a different remote access client (proprietary solution called Bomgar). Something FUBARed (I can't give an exact description of what happened, since I wasn't paying enough attention at the time). When I went to paste something on to the Win2008 client, I just got the last item in the Windows copy and paste buffer, not the item from my primary clipboard on Ubuntu.

At the time, I was also running [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) on the Ubuntu box, sharing mouse, keyboard and clipboard with a MacBook Pro. I've since rebooted the Linux box, and haven't re-started Bomgar or Synergy, but I still don't have clipboard support.

Here's the command line as I pulled it out of ps aux:

```
rdesktop -ubartonski -pXXXXXXXXXX -dNTDOMAIN -ncribbage -g1400x1050 -rsound:local -rclipboard:PRIMARYCLIPBOARD -5 win2k8.prod.mycompany.com
```

Note the flags **-rclipboard:PRIMARYCLIPBOARD** and **-5** (I.e. I am using RDPv5. Terminal Server Client isn't lying to me).

I checked was to make sure that things weren't getting stuck in the secondary clipboard buffer for some reason on the Linux side. I tried pasting from all three buffers, none of them worked.

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/224952/how-do-i-copy-and-paste-between-my-local-system-and-the-remote-system-when-using/224953#224953

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to logoff (as it closes all programs which may have work in them), the [following solution](http://patricksheedy.net/blog/fix-cut-and-paste-problems-with-remote-desktop/) worked for me:

open the cmd prompt, and enter:

```
taskkill.exe /f /im rdpclip.exe & rdpclip.exe
```

you may also put it in `fixrdp.bat` file on your Desktop for easy access

Comment: I no longer work in a Windows environment, but I'll accept this answer if it gets a couple more up-doots.

Answer (score 9):

Logging out of Windows2008 then logging back in solved the problem.

... it's always the simple stuff ...

Comment: Worked for me to with Win7

Comment: The same from Ubuntu to remote CentOS. I had to specify also `-r clipboard:CLIPBOARD`